# How to extend ontology with other standard ontologies in Protégé?

Tags: rdf, semantics, owl, ontology, protege4

I am building an ontology using Protégé, but wan to extend it with other standard ontologies such as frbr, prov, and org. Is there a standard way to integrate our ontology with these standard ontologies or can we merge these ontologies with each other? I want to do these tasks using Protégé.

Answer (score 9):

Unless I'm missing something about your question (which didn't really provide enough information to diagnose the problem that you're actually having), this is what `owl:imports` is for.  You can import other (OWL) ontologies into your own.  In Protégé, you just use the **Ontology imports** under the **Active Ontology** tab to specify ontologies that you want to import.

[image: the ontology imports tab]

Remember that Protégé is an OWL tool, so if you're importing something with that feature, that something should be an OWL ontology too.  You'll have mixed luck if you try to import RDF(S) vocabularies. E.g., you might get the properties, but as annotation properties rather than object and datatype properties.

There are some related questions and answers on answers.semanticweb.com:

- [Re-use of terms from ontology.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150114004519/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/24337/re-use-of-terms-from-ontology)
- [Dublin Core reusing in owl ontology](https://web.archive.org/web/20150111114738/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/18021/dublin-core-reusing-in-owl-ontology)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239706/how-to-import-geosparql-to-your-ontology