# Defining schema for the RDF/OWL

Tags: schema, rdf, semantic-web, owl, rdfs

I am using RDF as the data model for my meta data.
The meta data will contain IOPE and the other parameter, like efficiency/accuracy which are not the part of IOPE but part of metadata for a process.
There is schema for the process (http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.0/Process.owl) which includes the IOPE.

1) How can I define a schema for other parameter to be present in my RDF file ?

2) I am using Protege but I also can't find a way to use the Process schema or any existing schema.

Comment: "I also can't a way to use the Process schema"   I think you forgot a word, but I think that you probably just want your ontology to *import* the process.owl ontology.  See [How to extend ontology with other standard ontologies in Protégé?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24260244/1281433)

Comment: "How can I define a schema for other parameter to be present in my RDF file ?"  It's not clear what you're asking.  A schema or ontology is typically just a bunch of declarations that describe the vocabulary you're defining.  If you want to use another property, just declare it in your schema and, as a matter of good practice, add some annotations (e.g., rdfs:label, rdfs:comment) describing how it should be used.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks. Actually I have tried to import using the option mentioned in the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/24260244/1281433. It doesn't show anything in the Direct Imports Tab. It seems to be problem with the location.
Actually as Process structure defined in the Process.owl. Similarly I want to add some meta data for the Process in a structure like we have XML schemas and used it to define the ontology.

Comment: You didn't say in the question that you had tried that.  It's important to tell us what you've tried.  Also,  I just tried creating an ontology that imports that process.owl, and the process.owl is found without a problem.  It *does* say, however, that one of the file that it imports couldn't be found.  You might be able to find a copy of that online somewhere (e.g., the wayback machine) and resolve the import manually.  There's a big difference between "I can't import X" and "I can import X, but it imports Y which I can't import."  It's important to describe the problem and all its details.