# How to import geosparql to your ontology?

Tags: rdf, geospatial, owl, ontology, protege

Based on this: [How to extend ontology with other standard ontologies in Protégé?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260244/how-to-extend-ontology-with-other-standard-ontologies-in-prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9), I am really worried on how to import geosparql in an ontology I just created.

I *think* that importing geosparql means to import this to my ontology in Protege: http://schemas.opengis.net/geosparql/1.0/geosparql_vocab_all.rdf

My ontology is Saved As *RDF/XML syntax* and the file that contains it has a *.owl* extension.

How to safely import geosparql in my ontology (Protege 5.0.0 beta)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `.rdf` and `.owl` are acceptable extensions for `OWL` ontologies saved as `RDF/XML`.

If your ontology imports the geosparql ontology, the extension is not important - what's important is that Protege can find an ontology whose ontology IRI is `http://schemas.opengis.net/geosparql/1.0/geosparql_vocab_all.rdf`.

This can happen in multiple ways: Protege might remember that a local file it has parsed before contains this ontology (the file name is not relevant - this is called IRI redirection or IRI mapping), or it will attempt to download the ontology taking the ontology IRI as a document URL.

In this case, the only constraint is that the ontology IRI is a resolvable URL.

Comment: So how should I do it? Create a `geosparql_vocab_all.rdf` file locally on my machine, copy paste what the IRI (http://schemas.opengis.net/geosparql/1.0/geosparql_vocab_all.rdf) has in that file and import that file, as Joshua's answer shows in my linked question?

Comment: You don't need to download the file. Just use http://schemas.opengis.net/geosparql/1.0/geosparql_vocab_all.rdf as in Joshua's answer.

Comment: OK thanks! Hope I am importing the right URI for geosparql. ;p